# What is the purpose of a single element form-group in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap documentation contains code as part of a [navbar example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default):

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

What is the purpose of the `div` with the `form-group` class here? The name suggests that it is for grouping form elements but there is only one child element.

Comment: I don't think there's much reasoning behind it. Perhaps a copy-paste job, perhaps it was written so that if you were to add a prepend, append, whatever else you might add, you could easily do that. There's no difference in the visual aspect, anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At its most basic, it sets some spacing between elements. This is from the Bootstrap CSS file:

```css
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

It does much more if you dig through their CSS. Like act the same as `.row` in `.form-horizontal`, like:

```css
.form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

In the case of the navbar in your example, this is in their CSS:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-form .form-group {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0;            
        vertical-align: middle;
     }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-form .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .navbar-form .form-group:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

View the full CSS file for Bootstrap [here](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css)